# Are infinite groups permutation groups?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

I have known Cayley's Theorem for some time now, which shows that all finite groups are permutation groups (*secretly*, as a previous mathematics teacher of mine might have put it). However, the thought occurs to me whether we can prove that this is true for infinite groups.

In [this amazing MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126158/a-mother-of-all-groups-what-kind-of-structures-have-mother-of-alls/126173#126173), they show what appears to a construction of what I now call the Mother Class-Group, but only implicitly suggest that this contains all other groups as sub-groups. Why is it? Is it to do with the fact that all finite groups are linear?

Comment: What proof of Cayley's theorem do you know?  Does it really require the group to be finite?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The proof I'm familiar with is the standard one which constructs a permutation of the group for each element and you're right - there's no reason any of the arguments used in it require the group to be finite! I think I only thought it did because the book I first read it in stated it as if worked only in the finite case and also my general weariness to assume something naturally extends to an infinite case.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: If I could accept your comment as an answer, I would!

Comment: @JasonDeVito: So, does this mean that *all* groups are linear? That *is* remarkable! Infinite groups have an isomorphic action on matrices of infinite-dimensional spaces? *Very cool*!

Comment: Seems to me the only point to "finite" is then it's more natural to say "permutation" instead of "bijection"...

Comment: @Isky Mathews sorry but not all groups are linear - this is only necessarily true for finite groups... (using representation theory)

Comment: @Daniele1234: Ah yes, I just looked up the definition of a linear group and it says that they have been linear transformations over a *finite dimensional* space, which is where my observation fails. Still, it *is* true that every group can be seen as a set of matrices working over some space, *if* you allow infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Isky Mathews Be careful with infinite dimensional spaces, not as simple as at first glance! Also, this is true by definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just glancing at that MO post, here's an analogous construction of a mother of all groups that's perhaps simpler, and is in any case quite explicit. **Note** All I'm claiming here is that it's a "proper-class group" that contains every group as a subgroup; in particular I'm not claiming that it does the other mode-theoretic things that the "monster group" is said to do in that MO post. (**Edit:** Turns out it was a little too simple, running into  some illegal set theory. See **Oops** below...)

Let  $O$ be the class of all ordinals. Let $M$ be the class of all bijections $\phi:O\to O$ *such that* there exists $\alpha$ with $\phi(\beta)=\beta$ for all $\beta>\alpha$.

Then $M$ is what they call a "proper-class group", which is to say it's "a group except that it's a proper class, too large to be a set".

It's easy to see that if $G$ is a genuine "set-sized" group then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $M$: The proof of Caley's theorem shows that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the bijections of some set $S$, and there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that there exists a bijection of $S$ onto $\alpha$; the group of bijections of $\alpha$ is a subgroup of $M$.

**Oops.** The elements of $M$ above are themselves proper classes; that's not allowed, proper classes are not supposed to be elements.

**Almost fix:** If $\phi:\alpha\to\alpha$ is a bijection then $\phi$ defines a bijection $\psi\to O$ such that $\psi(\beta)=\beta$ for all $\beta\ge\alpha$. So redefine $M$ to be the class of all bijections from some ordinal to itself; define the composition of two such things to be the $\phi$ that corresponds to the composition of the corresponding $\psi$s. (That is, $\psi_{\phi_1\phi_2}=\psi_{\phi_1}\circ\psi_{\phi_2}$.)

That doesn't quite work either, because one $\psi$ arises from many different $\phi$s. Obvious solution is to define an equivalence relation blah blah - oops, the equivalence classes are again proper classes. But for each $\psi$ there is a *minimal* $\phi$.

**fix:** Say $S_\alpha$ is the set of all bijections $\phi:\alpha\to\alpha$ such that the set of $\beta\in\alpha$ with $\phi(\beta)\ne\beta$ is cofinal. Now any nontrivial bijection $\psi:O\to O$ arises from a unique $\phi\in\bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$. Let $M=\{\emptyset\}\cup\bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$. (Now $\emptyset$ becomes the identity element of $M$.)

Comment: Thanks for this! The thing I worried most about was the fact that, no matter the size of set that $G$ acted, $G$ could be seen to be isomorphic to a subgroup of the bijections upon a set of size $|G|$, but this was already answered for me in a comment and you made other aspects clearer.